# Fatal error when initializing core config - trying to deploy chaincode - fabric release version v1.1.0-preview

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to deploy Node JS Chaincode on the new fabric release version v1.1.0-preview by following this video - Node JS Chaincode support for Hyperledger Fabric v1.1 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzwR0dwzXNs)

Commands:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME="logic:v0" npm start -- --peer.address grpc://192.168.0.4:7052

> logic@1.0.0 start /Users/simonmullaney/block-aviation_angular/lib
> node logic.js "--peer.address" "grpc://192.168.x.x:7052"

[2018-01-26T15:47:44.701] [INFO] lib/chaincode.js - Registering with peer grpc://192.168.x.x:7052 as chaincode "logic:v0"
[2018-01-26T15:47:44.723] [INFO] lib/handler.js - Successfully registered with peer node. State transferred to "established"
[2018-01-26T15:47:44.723] [INFO] lib/handler.js - Successfully established communication with peer node. State transferred to "ready"
```

Then in another terminal I do:

```
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/Users/simonmullaney/Fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp peer chaincode install -l node -n logic -v v0 -p /Users/simonmullaney/block-aviation_angular/lib
```

But I then get the following error:

```
panic: Fatal error when initializing core config : Error when reading core config file: Unsupported Config Type ""


goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x7a0be0, 0xc4202216f0)
    /opt/go/go1.7.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
main.main()
    /w/workspace/fabric-binaries-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:94 +0x852
```

Does anyone know a fix to this?